# как поменять местами строчки в матрице c#

Tags: c#

нужна помощь)
не обязательно код, хватит подсказки, буду признателен)

есть матрица:

```
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
```

нужно поменять местами:

```
4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 
4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4
```

код:

```
var array = new int[4, 4]; 
for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++) 
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++) 
    { 
        array[j, i] = i + 1; // array[j, i] = j+1;
    } 
} 

for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++) 
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++) 
    { 
        Console.Write(array[i, j].ToString(" #0")); 
    } 
    Console.WriteLine(); 
}
```

Comment: Может лучше русскими словами пояснить что с чем и где надо менять? На первый взгляд надо реверсировать четные строки. Это так?

Answer (score 1):

Псевдо-код:

1. Идти по матрице сверху-вниз
2. Проверить строку на четность, используя оператор `%`, который
   возвращает остаток от деления.

Если находишься на нечетной строке, то сортируй от большего к меньшему

Если находишься на четной, то от меньшего к большему.

Повторять до конца.

Comment: Приколисты)))))